# div with images inside php while

Tags: php

I need your help with my code,
I'm starting with PHP, I saw that we can show pictures on a page just adding the pic in the folder.
I tried different way but without success, so here i am asking you.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <?php
        $directory = "images";
        $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");

        foreach($images as $image)
        {


        echo    "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 nopadding photo'>
                <a class='lightbox'>
                    <img class='fancybox' src=".$image" alt=".$image" data-big=".$image" >
                </a>
            </div>";



        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I would like to put the pic inside a div for it to be responsive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have some minor issues with your string concatenation.
The code should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php
        $directory = "images";
        $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 nopadding photo'>
                <a class='lightbox'>
                    <img class='fancybox' src='".$image."' alt='".$image."' data-big='".$image."' >
                </a>
            </div>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this syntax in html templates, it creates less confusion.

```
 <?php
        $directory = "images";
        $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");            
 ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 nopadding photo">
                    <a class="lightbox">
                        <img class="fancybox"
                             src="<?= $image ?>"
                             alt="<?= $image ?>"
                             data-big="<?= $image ?>" >
                    </a>
                </div>            
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```